# Custom Action - Selecting the PXCache to act upon

Tags: acumatica

TL;DR - I am creating a time clock feature on the Employee Time Activities Screen (EP307000). How does one select/use the default view already built into a screen (or graph)?

---

I have two custom actions - Stop_Timer and Pause_Timer.
I could not figure out how to act upon the "Activity" view already built into the Graph (PX.Objects.EP.EmployeeActivitiesEntry).

To solve the problem, I wrote my own PXSelect statement (seen below).
But, by writing my own PXSelect statement, I broke the filter already present on the screen. Additionally, I seem to have lost the ability to use the "DependonGrid" property of the "PXDSCallbackCommand".

```js
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data.EP;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CT;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Data;
using PX.TM;
using OwnedFilter = PX.Objects.CR.OwnedFilter;
using PX.Api;
using PX.Objects;

namespace PX.Objects.EP
{
    public class EmployeeActivitiesEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<EmployeeActivitiesEntry>
    {
        #region Select

        public PXSelectJoin<EPActivityApprove,
                    InnerJoin<PMTask,
                            On<PMTask.taskID, Equal<EPActivityApprove.projectTaskID>>,
                    LeftJoin<PMTimeActivity,
                            On<PMTimeActivity.noteID, Equal<EPActivityApprove.origNoteID>>>>,
                    Where<EPActivityApprove.ownerID, Equal<Current<EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter.ownerID>>,
                            And<EPActivityApprove.trackTime, Equal<True>>>> Activity;
        #endregion

        #region Actions

        public PXAction<PX.Objects.EP.EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter> Stop_Timer;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Stop")]
        protected void stop_Timer()
        {
            
            EPActivityApprove row = Activity.Current;
            PMTimeActivityExt pMTimeActivityExt = PXCache<PMTimeActivity>.GetExtension<PMTimeActivityExt>(row);

            throw new PXException("You pressed Stop Timer for the row containing Date =  "  + (DateTime)row.Date);

            // All of my actions

            Base.Caches[typeof(PMTimeActivity)].Update(pMTimeActivityExt);
            Base.Caches[typeof(EPActivityApprove)].Update(row);
            
        }

        public PXAction<PX.Objects.EP.EmployeeActivitiesEntry.PMTimeActivityFilter> Pause_Timer;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Pause/Play")]
        protected void pause_Timer()
        {
            EPActivityApprove row = Activity.Current;
            PMTimeActivityExt pMTimeActivityExt = PXCache<PMTimeActivity>.GetExtension<PMTimeActivityExt>(row);

            throw new PXException("You pressed Pause Timer for the row containing Date =  "  + (DateTime)row.Date);
            
            // All of my actions

            Base.Caches[typeof(PMTimeActivity)].Update(pMTimeActivityExt);
            Base.Caches[typeof(EPActivityApprove)].Update(row);

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

[see customization package stored on Github - for laughter at my poor coding skills](https://github.com/paulgilfoy/StackOverflow--73208316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with the view in the base graph, just refer to it as **Base.Activity** in your graph extension.  Accessing views and actions work similarly to how you did **Base.Caches** at the bottom of your code.

The current Activity record => Base.Activity.Current

```
EPActivityApprove row = Base.Activity.Current;
EPActivityApproveExt rowExt = row.GetExtension<>EPActivityApproveExt>();
rowExt.MyField = "My Value";
Base.Activity.Cache.Update(rowExt);
```

If you need to press the save button at some point...

```
Base.Save.Press();
```

Comment: Brian,  thank you! The solution seems so obvious to me now. This is a huge help! Thank you, man.